# Ubuntu 18.04 another DNS server

Tags: networking, dns

In Settings -> Network -> Wired -> Configuration Properties -> Default Route and DNS are shown DNS, given by my provider. When I go to websites my DNS numbers started to be different, DNS leak site says that my DNS is from Google, but it's not my own that was given by my Provider.

I don't understand why in my Settings menu it shows the DNS given by my Provider, but sites say that it's not? I did nothing to change DNS. I don't even know how to do it, because I'm new to Ubuntu, but I want to understand who or which application changes my DNS settings to Google all the time?

[image]

Comment: Are you using a vpn to connect to the net?

Comment: If your not connecting from a vpn those are just the dns servers your isp’s dns was routed through if you are connected through a vpn you have a dns leak

Comment: No, I am not using any vpn. In contrast, when I use vpn, it changes to vpn's dns. And this happens right after loading a system. DNS leak site shows my real IP adress, and when it comes to DNS it shows like that. I used another IP\DNS leak site, that one shows 2 DNS: first one is Google (like that on the image), second one - my real. That's really strange.

Answer (score 0):

From a dns leak test if you are connected to the net via a vpn the listed dns servers should all be the ones supplied by your vpn if there are other dns servers listed it means you have a dns leak if your not connected via vpn then don’t worry about them they are just the servers your isp’s dns sever was routed to.

Comment: I do not use any VPN. If I used, that would not be a question.

Comment: Maybe a system itself configured to Google's DNS? but I can't find the application, that configured DNS this way.

Comment: Could be on Ubuntu it is under system then network then setting then dns.  Assuming your using default install.